# How to target body in javascript DOM event

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to modify a style which looks like:

```
<body class="theme1">
```

I would like to target this body's class and make that to just `<body>`. The problem is that, even though I would normally find elements using `document.getElementById('someId')` or by `tagName` in this case, I don't know how to find the target.

Comment: When is your JS executed? The element has to exist before it can be modified

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `document.body` to get to it. To remove the class, you can use:

```
document.body.className = '';
```

This will change the contents of the `class` attribute to be the empty string, so it will remove all the classes the element might have.

Answer (score 4):

To remove class from 'body' tag use this:

```
document.body.removeAttribute('class');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target body via  .body  in JavaScript, see code below:

document.body.style.color = 'red';

```js
document.body.style.cssText = `
  color: red;
`

// note, you do NOT need <body></body>  in HTML to make this work
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.